# 401 Unauthorized when calling .ajax method in rails 3 application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm passing a ajax call to update data in my application through twitter bootstrap modal window. The ajax code is given below:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var link=$('#link_hash').val();
  $("#update_link").click(function(){
    console.log("I'm here");
     $.ajax({
            url: "profiles/update_link",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {link: link,data: $('#link_hash').val() },
            success: function(data) {
              // some code
            },
            error: function(data1) {
              // some code
             }
            });

        });
      });
```

I have modifies route.rb file to match it to my controllers "update_link" method.
The code in my method is given below:-

```
  def update_link
    @link=Link.find_by_link(params[:link])
    @tlink=Link.find_by_link(params[:data])
    logger.info "=========kkkkkkkkkkkkkk=================================#{@link.inspect}"
    logger.info "=========kkkkkkkkkkkkkk=================================#{@tlink.inspect}"
    logger.info "=========kkkkkkkkkkkkkk=================================#{params.inspect}"

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tlink.nil? 
         @link.update_attributes(:link => params[:data])

        ...some code....
      else
    ...some code...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So in the server log it's showing -

```
Started POST "/profiles/update_link" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-20 12:08:20 +0530
Processing by ProfilesController#update_link as HTML
  Parameters: {"link"=>"9bfzjp", "data"=>"9bfzjpaaa"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 6ms
```

So clearly **"logger.info"** is not showing up...Now after searching I was able to solve the WARNING but still 401 is present...How to solve this??

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your server log, you are not passing CSRF token, so rails automatically considers request to be malicious and flags it as unverified. default handling of unverified requests is to reset session. Can you comment out `protect_from_forgery` or add `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` to your controller to see if it the case?

If you want to include authenticity token in your ajax request (highly recommended) you can add it to headers in your ajax request:

```
headers: {
      'X-Transaction': 'POST Example',
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
```

Comment: I tried both. When I added "header:" in my ajax call in still showed 401 error. However When I added "skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token" it's actually doing the job but still in firebug showing an "406 Not Acceptable " error. Anyway it might be a problem in my ajax callback code. I'm looking into it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!` to your controller.